# Trouble connecting an async function to a PySide6 button signal

Tags: python, python-asyncio, pyside6

I'm currently working on a Python application using PySide6 for the GUI. I have a `QPushButton` and I want to connect its `clicked` signal to an asynchronous function, but I'm running into some issues.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Async Function Example")
        self.login_button = QPushButton("Login", self)
        self.login_button.clicked.connect(self.login_button_clicked)

    async def login_button_clicked(self):
        # Perform async tasks
        print("test async button clicked!")


app = QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

However, when I run this code, I receive the following error:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'MainWindow.login_button_clicked' was never awaited
  app.exec()
```

I understand that the error is caused by not awaiting the asynchronous function. I have tried using the await keyword before the method call when connecting the signal, but PySide6 doesn't directly support connecting asynchronous functions to signals.

I've also attempted to work around this by using a helper function or a coroutine runner, but without success.

Could someone please guide me on how to properly connect an asynchronous function to a PySide6 button signal? Is there a recommended approach or workaround for this situation? Any code examples or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and I have created a package to solve it.
The asyncio need to be setup properly to be able to work with PySide6.

Your code can be changed to:

```
pip install AsyncioPySide6
```

```py
import sys
from AsyncioPySide6 import AsyncioPySide6
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Async Function Example")
        self.login_button = QPushButton("Login", self)
        self.login_button.clicked.connect(self.login_button_clicked)

    def login_button_clicked(self):
        async def asyncTask():
            # Async wait for 4 seconds
            await asyncio.timeout(4)

            # Perform async tasks
            print("test async button clicked!")
            self.login_button.setEnabled(False)
        AsyncioPySide6.runTask(asyncTask())


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
with AsyncioPySide6.use_asyncio():
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Basically, you can execute any asynchronous task by using AsyncioPySide6.runTask.
You can even manipulate GUI components within async tasks without using QMetaObject.invoke.

Answer (score 0):

In any case, the button target must be a synchronous function. You can write code within it to forward the execution to a task running in an asyncio loop.

QT code uses its own loop and can co-operate with multi-threaded Python code - and it is not directly compatible with an asyncio loop - you have to make that bridge. Since the example you post has no code starting an asyncio loop running in parallel to your Qt GUI code, I supose you don't have any such thing yet, and just want to call an async function in another library.

If you don't have an asyncio loop running in your app, just write the code to launch such a loop and call your async function from there, if it is a one time thing.

More likely, you will want to have an asyncio loop running in another thread and just dispatch async co-routines to be run there - this should suffice:

```
import threading, asyncio

async_loop = None
def async_setup():
     global async_loop 
     async_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
     async_loop.run_forever()
...

class MainWindow(...):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ...
        self.login_button.clicked.connect(self.login_button_clicked)

    ...

    async def async_login(self, *args):
        # Perform async tasks
        print("test async button clicked!")

    def login_button_clicked(self):
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.async_login(...), async_loop)

...

async_thread = threading.Thread(target=async_setup())
async_thread.start()
app = QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```